EF Core 6 Arbitrarily Adding 'WHERE 1 = 0' Clause
I have moved my production code from an on-premises server to an Azure server. I noticed that most queries are returning 0 results, but when counting the rows, they return the correct count. After investigating using SQL Profiler, I noticed that EF Core is adding a "WHERE 1 = 0" condition to some queries, even though this was not added in the code.
I researched the issue and found answers suggesting that this could be due to differences between the backend model and the database schema (e.g., nullable fields in the database but not in the model). However, I double-checked class by class and table by table, and everything is identical.
In the following code, it correctly returns the total record count as 2, but the result set is an empty array (even though the database contains two records).
Here is one of services as example:
public async Task<PagedResultDTO<ApplicationOrganizationDTO>> GetAll(PaginationInputDTO<Guid> input)
{
    try
    {
        var query = _context.ApplicationOrganizations.AsQueryable();

      
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.SortBy))
        {
            //this will based on slected column
            query = input.SortType.Equals("DESC")? query.OrderByDescending(x => x.EnglishName):query.OrderBy(x=>x.EnglishName);
        }

        // Calculate the number of records to skip and take
        int recordsToSkip = (input.PageNumber - 1) * input.PageSize;
        int recordsToTake = input.PageSize;

        // Retrieve the records based on the pagination parameters
        var records = await query.Skip(recordsToSkip).Take(recordsToTake).ToListAsync();

        var result = new PagedResultDTO<ApplicationOrganizationDTO>
        {
            Results = _mapper.Map<List<ApplicationOrganizationDTO>>(records),
            TotalRecords = await query.CountAsync()
        };

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Here is the generated query from SQL Profiler:
SELECT [a].[Id], [a].[ActivationDurationInDays], [a].[ActivationStatus], [a].[ArabicName], [a].[CreationDate], [a].[EnglishName], [a].[LastEditDate], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[ShortName], [a].[Website]
FROM [ApplicationOrganizations] AS [a]
WHERE 0 = 1

I believe the fixes shouldn't be by the code, because same code and same database are working perfectly on-premises environment but on not on Azure.

WHERE 1=0 may be an optimization for a guaranteed FALSE condition. You can generate and log the query used by EF with query.ToQueryString(). Please post that query along with the unusual queries and the PageNumber, PageSize values. It's far more likely that the paging parameters are wrong

BTW the query you need to check is query.Skip(recordsToSkip).Take(recordsToTake) not just query. Perhaps one of the parameters is negative? Perhaps recordsToTake is 0? Does the actual code contain any dynamic conditions that are guaranteed to be FALSE?

Probably recordsToTake is less or equal to zero. Some DB engines fail to execute such queries and EF generates false positive condition.

Almost certainly there is an implicit contradiction in the query, so it's optimizing it by turning it into a WHERE FALSE condition. Without further info it's not possible to say.

@Charlieface, I remember that saw similar issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30041

@SvyatoslavDanyliv if it was less or equal zero it wont return any value On-premises

@siggemannen query added.

@AbdulazizBurghal, so? Have you checked that 'input.PageSize' is not zero?

Check your pagesize, I suspect it may be 0 considering the query did not implement any pagination. EF may have inserted the WHERE clause as a "take 0 rows" condition. Also I recommend using Automapper's Results = query.ProjectTo<ApplicationOrganizationDTO>(mapperConfig) instead of Results = _mapper.Map<List<ApplicationOrganizationDTO>>(records). It will compose a more efficient query for just the values needed for the DTO.

@AbdulazizBurghal EF Core doesn't know where the code is running. The query would be the same. Log the actual parameter values instead of assuming they're the same.

SvyatoslavDanyliv and Panagiotis Kanavos
yes it is zero, and that what causes the issue, although I'm working on EF Core 6 not on 7 as the GitHub link mentioned, I will share the full details of the use case and how its happening later, you can add it as answer to give you the points and I will add another answer with full details for debugging and solution.
